# Separating game logic from render thread

Tags: language-agnostic, logic, abstraction

I have the following structure in my game:

- `Engine` has properties containing a `PhysicsWorld` and an `Entity`
  array.
- An `Entity` has properties containing a `PhysicsBody`, a `Skin` and
  an `update()` method that moves its `Skin` to the latest
  `PhysicsBody` position.
- The `Skin` is the visual representation of the `PhysicsBody`. They're
  both extended to be the shape we want, so if we want the entity to be
  a circle, I usually create both a `CircleBody` and a `CircleSkin` and
  assign both to an `Entity`.
- `Engine` calls `Game.PhysicsWorld.step()` every frame, then calls
  `Entity.update()` for every `Entity` so they can visually reflect the
  physics stepping.

I am not happy with how this game's abstraction is working, and I think having the game logic and render thread being basically two different properties for each `Entity` is not a good solution. I also think the `Skin` class and the way it integrates with the `PhysicsBody` class is not ideal.

How can I change my game's structure so it has better abstraction and works in a cleaner way?